# OSRM: Getting output in Flatbuffers format for route service

Tags: request, flatbuffers, osrm

I host OSRM v5.24.0 on my local machine using a dataset preprocessed with CH (Contraction Hierarchies) pipeline. And I need to get the output of route response in flatbuffers format. But I couldn't find the correct query for that.

API Documentation reference: http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.24.0/api/#requests

[image: OSRM request]

The query I am using (Postman):

> https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/73.14568712144677,-0.6875788801118562;73.13504135080412,-0.682499947378062?overview=full&alternatives=false&steps=false&geometries=geojson&format=flatbuffers

Result I get:

```
{
    "message": "Query string malformed close to position 156",
    "code": "InvalidQuery"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. Following is the correct get request to get the response in flatbuffers format:

> https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/73.14568712144677,-0.6875788801118562;73.13504135080412,-0.682499947378062.flatbuffers?overview=full&alternatives=false&steps=false&geometries=geojson